# Javascript not working in Ruby on Rails Deployment mode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, deployment

I cannot get any javascript to run when my Ruby on Rails project is in deployment mode.  I have a js at vendor/assets/javascript/theme/index-slider.js.  It has an alert in this file to test that the javascript is working:

```
alert('TestTestTest');
```

When I run the project in the development mode, all the javascript runs properly.  Additionally, if I add `<script>alert("Testme");</script>` to my index.html.erb file, that javascript runs in production mode.

I have been running `rake assets:precompile` and `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` when making changes as well as restarting the server

How can I get Javascript to run in Production mode? (Also I am rather new to Ruby on Rails so I am not sure which files/information I should include to be helpful.)  Thanks.

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap
//= require theme/bootstrap.min
//= require theme/flexslider
//= require theme/index-slider
//= require theme/jquery.countdown.min
//= require theme/jquery.isotope.min
//= require theme/theme
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Did you required it in application.js file

Comment: Yes, I've included theme/index-slider in application.js.  I've added the application.js.  Also I see the TestTestTest alert in the javascript assets in Chromes dev tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the issue lies in the application.js file.  I've added bootstrap into my project by hand as well as a boostrap theme.  I've found that for whatever reason, the //= require bootstrap/bootstrap line should not be included above the theme I have chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile assets for your production as well

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: I tried that but it hasn't had any effect.  The javascript still isn't running.  I also confirmed that the file I want to run is in the compiled application.js file.

Comment: Can you see your js files included in your html page on production?

Comment: Yes I can. All the files are compiled into one file though.  I've tinkered with having the compression turned off in production with no effect.  The javascript still does not run in deployment mode.